# How to convert entire DataTable column into a string? - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

In this project I'm working on, I have to create a bunch of pie charts using SQL queries.

There are 2 phases of SQL

First, I want to collect the names of Machines operating during the time frame the user has selected and place it in a DataTable.

```
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)
```

For this example the machine names I collected is

```
--------------
|    MacId   |
--------------
|    A01     |
|    A02     |
|    C01     |
--------------
```

For the second phase I want to use the data collected in the first phase and reference it into another SQL query. My idea is to have the content in the table to convert into a string, like so:

```
'A01', 'A02', 'C01'
```

That way I'll only need to run the 2nd SQL query once instead of having to rely on For - Next statement to get the data, which was what I used the last time resulting in long loading times, expecially when there are 30+ machines.

How can I get this result? I've been thinking about it for 2 days now and I have no idea how to start.

Edit:

For some context here is my current code. Please ignore the mess.

```
Sub draw_chart1() 'All Machines

    Dim check1, check2, fi, cnt
    Dim seperator As String = ", "
    Dim columnindex As Integer = 0

    Dim myConnectionString As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & SQLDB_pp.ConnectionString
    fi = 0
    cnt = 0

    PlaceHolder1.Dispose()
    PlaceHolder2.Dispose()

    'Get all machines
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)

    Dim result As String = String.Join(seperator, dt1.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) "'" + r(columnindex).ToString() + "'")).TrimEnd(seperator.ToCharArray())

    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim query As String


    'Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
    '                                        & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & check1 & "') ) Z " _
    '                                        & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
    '                                        & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
    '                                        & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
    '                                        & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & check1 & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
    '                                        & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")
    'Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)

    'For q As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1

    'check1 = dt1.DataSet.ToString
    'check1 = dt1.Rows(q)(0).ToString() '(0) means column, since query1 only search for 1 column, it uses 0 = 1ST COLUMN

    query = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
            & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ({0}) ) Z " _
            & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
            & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
            & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
            & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ({0}) group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
            & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName", result)

    dt = GetData(query)

    'Next

    'dt = GetData(query)

    For a As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

        check2 = dt.Rows(a)(0).ToString()

        Dim mychart As Chart = New Chart
        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend

        'Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query) '30 sec to process
        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As Integer() = New Integer(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Next

        mychart.Width = 600
        mychart.Height = 400

        mychart.ChartAreas.Clear()
        mychart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea2")

        mychart.Series.Clear()
        mychart.Series.Add(0)
        mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)

        mychart.Titles.Clear()
        mychart.Titles.Add("[" & a + 1 & "] " & check2.ToString.ToUpper)
        mychart.Titles(0).Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Titles(0).BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise
        mychart.Titles(0).ForeColor = Color.Black

        mychart.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        mychart.Series(0).LegendText = "#VALX"
        mychart.Series(0)("BarLabelStyle") = "Center"
        mychart.Series(0)("pointWidth") = "1"
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowColor = Color.Gray
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowOffset = 10

        mychart.Series(0).LabelBackColor = Drawing.Color.Cornsilk
        mychart.Series(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

        mychart.Series(0).LegendToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True

        mychart.Series(0).CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark"
        'new
        Chart1.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").BorderDashStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
        mychart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).BorderColor = Color.Black

        mychart.PaletteCustomColors = {Drawing.Color.Black, Drawing.Color.White, Drawing.Color.Blue, Drawing.Color.Yellow, Drawing.Color.Red, Drawing.Color.Orange, Drawing.Color.Green}

        mychart.Legends.Clear()
        mychart.Legends.Add(0)
        mychart.Legends(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Legends(0).Docking = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom

        mychart.DataBind()

        If (a + 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(mychart)

        End If

        If (a + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then

            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(mychart)

        End If

    Next
End Sub

 Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal query As String) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    '  Dim constr As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLDB_pp").ConnectionString
    'Dim con As New SqlConnection(SQLDB_pp)
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = SQLDB_pp
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
    sda.Fill(dt)
    Return dt

End Function
```

Edit 2:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.Append("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
            & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in (")

    Dim params As New List(Of SqlParameter)()

    Dim max As Integer = result.Length - 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To max

        If i = max Then
            sb.Append("MacID" & i.ToString())
        Else
            sb.Append("MacID" & i.ToString() & ", ")
        End If
        params.Add(New SqlParameter("MacID" & i.ToString(), result(i)))
    Next

    sb.Append(") ) Z " _
            & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
            & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
            & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
            & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in (")

    Dim params2 As New List(Of SqlParameter)()

    Dim max2 As Integer = result.Length - 1

    For j As Integer = 0 To max2

        If j = max2 Then
            sb.Append("MacID" & j.ToString())
        Else
            sb.Append("MacID" & j.ToString() & ", ")
        End If
        params2.Add(New SqlParameter("MacID" & j.ToString(), result(j)))
    Next

    sb.Append(") group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
            & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")

    Dim q As String = sb.ToString()
```

Edit 4:

This is the full code for the sub I'm having problems with. This is the original code before any modifications with slow load times during the 2nd SQL.

```
Sub draw_chart1() 'All Machines

    Dim check1, check2, fi, cnt

    Dim sql
    Dim myConnectionString As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & SQLDB_pp.ConnectionString
    fi = 0
    cnt = 0

    PlaceHolder1.Dispose()
    PlaceHolder2.Dispose()
    'Get all machines
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)


    'Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
    '                                        & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & check1 & "') ) Z " _
    '                                        & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
    '                                        & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
    '                                        & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
    '                                        & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & check1 & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
    '                                        & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")
    'Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)

    For q As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1

        check1 = dt1.Rows(q)(0).ToString()

        Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
                                            & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & check1 & "') ) Z " _
                                            & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
                                            & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
                                            & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
                                            & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & check1 & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
                                            & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")

        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query) '47 sec to process



        Dim mychart As Chart = New Chart
        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend

        'Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query) '30 sec to process
        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As Integer() = New Integer(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            ' y(i) = dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Next

        'Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)
        'Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
        'mychart.Width = Unit.Pixel(Session("sw") - 100)
        'mychart.Height = Unit.Pixel((Session("sh") / 2) - 88)

        mychart.Width = 600
        mychart.Height = 400

        mychart.ChartAreas.Clear()
        mychart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")

        mychart.Series.Clear()
        mychart.Series.Add(0)
        mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)

        mychart.Titles.Clear()
        mychart.Titles.Add("[" & q + 1 & "] " & check1.ToString.ToUpper)
        mychart.Titles(0).Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Titles(0).BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise
        mychart.Titles(0).ForeColor = Color.Black

        mychart.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        '  mychart.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
        mychart.Series(0).LegendText = "#VALX"
        mychart.Series(0)("BarLabelStyle") = "Center"
        mychart.Series(0)("pointWidth") = "1"
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowColor = Color.Gray
        mychart.Series(0).ShadowOffset = 10

        mychart.Series(0).LabelBackColor = Drawing.Color.Cornsilk
        mychart.Series(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

        'Chart1.Series(0).LabelToolTip = "#LABEL Percent: #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).LegendToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"
        mychart.Series(0).ToolTip = "#VALX - #PERCENT"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True

        mychart.Series(0).CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark"
        'new
        Chart1.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside"

        mychart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").BorderDashStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
        mychart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None
        mychart.Series(0).BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        mychart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2
        mychart.Series(0).BorderColor = Color.Black

        mychart.PaletteCustomColors = {Drawing.Color.Black, Drawing.Color.White, Drawing.Color.Blue, Drawing.Color.Yellow, Drawing.Color.Red, Drawing.Color.Orange, Drawing.Color.Green}

        mychart.Legends.Clear()
        mychart.Legends.Add(0)
        'Chart1.Legends(0).Enabled = True
        ''Chart1.Legends(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreenplace
        mychart.Legends(0).Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        mychart.Legends(0).Docking = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom
        'Chart1.Legends(0).Alignment = Drawing.StringAlignment.Center
        'Chart1.Legends(0).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent

        mychart.DataBind()

        'myplace.Visible = True
        If (q + 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(mychart)
            ' Dim spacer As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<p />")
            ' PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(spacer)
        End If
        'Exit For
        If (q + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then

            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(mychart)
            'Dim spacer As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<p />")
            ' PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(spacer)

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably what you need to convert single-column table to a `String` is `Dim result As String = String.Join(",", DataTableName.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("MacId")).ToArray())`.

Comment: Ok. Then if I want to implement it into my SQL, should I enter it like so? `... and MacID in ('" & result & "')...`

Comment: Just use `String.Format` to format the query with comma-separated values and use it for `MySqlCommand`, e.g. `Dim command = String.Format("SELECT [something] FROM [tablename] WHERE FIND_IN_SET(MacId, {0})", YourResultString)` or use TVP for that.

Comment: That's weird... I added that and now some of my machines are reported as invalid column name.

Comment: Hold up. Let me place my full sub here. Gives y'all some context.

Comment: I already figured out you can use StringBuilder to build `WHERE IN` query with parameters, based from the string array created with above statement rather than passing the comma-separated string directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of trial and error, I finally got the string to work properly.

Note to self: Having a GridView to check the DataTable contents is a huge help.

Now my code basically looks like so:

```
    Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT A.MacID FROM dbo.tblMachine A LEFT JOIN  dbo.tblDataHdr b on a.MacID = b.MacID where DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND '" & TextBox3.Text & "' ORDER BY A.MACID")
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)


    Dim result As String = dt1.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x("MacId").ToString()).Aggregate(Function(a, b) String.Concat(a & "'" & "," & "'" & b))


    Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT Z.MacID, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a " _
                                            & "join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName <> 'ON'  ) b on b.EventName <> ''  and MacID in ('" & result & "') ) Z " _
                                            & "LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) " _
                                            & "as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MacID, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur " _
                                            & "WHERE DayID between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID WHERE DayID " _
                                            & "between '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'  AND A.MacID in ('" & result & "') group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a " _
                                            & "ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName")
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(query)

'Use this to help check the DataTable/Strings
GridView2.DataSource = dt 'change what you want to check accordingly
GridView2.DataBind()
```

By using GridView and binding the data to each query really helps in letting me see how the data looks. And the data shown in `dt` looks perfect.

Now my next problem is actually using the data to create a pie chart for each machine. But I'll post that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Join()` to join all `DataTable` column values by converting the `DataTable` column into string array first:

```
Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetData(query1)

Dim arr As String() = dt1.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("MacId")).ToArray()

Dim result As String = String.Join(",", arr)
```

Or use this line:

```
Dim result As String = table.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x("MacId").ToString()).Aggregate(Function(a, b) String.Concat(a, "," & b))
```

Afterwards, the output string can be passed into query string with table-valued parameters, or using `StringBuilder` to add parameters for each element of string array created by `ToArray()` with `WHERE IN` query:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

' example query string
sb.Append("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName IN (")

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

' note: array is zero-based
Dim max As Integer = arr.Length - 1

For i As Integer = 0 To max
    If i = max Then
       sb.Append("@MacId" & i.ToString())
    Else
       sb.Append("@MacId" & i.ToString() & ",")
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MacId" & i.ToString(), arr(i))
Next

sb.Append(")")

Dim query As String = sb.ToString()

cmd.CommandText = query

' execute the query
```

**Update:**

Since the query executed inside a function, you need to pass the query parameters to the function:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

' example query string
sb.Append("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName IN (")

Dim params As New List(Of SqlParameter)()

For i As Integer = 0 To max
    If i = max Then
       sb.Append("@MacId" & i.ToString())
    Else
       sb.Append("@MacId" & i.ToString() & ",")
    End If
    params.Add(New SqlParameter("@MacId" & i.ToString(), arr(i)))
Next

sb.Append(")")

Dim query As String = sb.ToString()

dt = GetData(query, params)
```

**Function contents**

```
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal query As String, Optional ByVal parameters As List(Of SqlParameter) = Nothing) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)

    If parameter IsNot Nothing Then
       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray())
    End If

    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = SQLDB_pp
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
    sda.Fill(dt)
    Return dt

End Function
```

Comment: I tried out the method you gave, since my SQL refers to my 1st query twice I had to use the `sb.append` twice as well. But I noticed when the code passes through my `Private Shared Function` I keep getting a double `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` error. What does that mean?

Comment: Incorrect syntax error caused because the last parameter contained additional comma `,`, which should be removed when the loop reaching last value inside the array.

Comment: if I'm using `Dim result` only, then for `Dim max as Integer` will I set to `result.Length - 1`?

Comment: If `result` is a string array, yes, the max value must be set to `result.Length - 1` because array has zero-based index. For the last index, you should remove the comma to build the query statement with `IN` clause.

Comment: Now I got some error on `Private Shared Function` again. `Invalid column name 'MacID154'.` to `Invalid column name 'MacID0'.`

Comment: Make sure that the `MacIDXXX` passed as parameter names, not column names depending on database provider you're using. Also you need to pass query parameters as function parameter with `Nothing` as default value so that you can reuse it for other queries which doesn't require parameters.

Comment: Well I followed and my SQL is getting more complicated. During testing another error popped up again. `The variable name '@MacID0' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.` Since the SQL is too large, I'll post it in my question as reference.

Comment: Since `@MacIDXXX` parameter name is already declared on first for-loop, you can opt for another parameter name in the second for-loop. Note that parameter names are just placeholders, it must have unique names.

Comment: I changed the parameter name in 2nd for loop to params2 and I still got the same `Invalid Column Name` error again... Changes is in Edit as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184384/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-hjh93).

Comment: can't use chat... Using office internet and chat is blocked... Company policy and all.

Comment: You're not supplying `@` prefix for parameter names, without that prefix the parameters are wrongly treated as column names. Have you read [using parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/parameters?view=sql-server-2017) before?

Comment: I see now. Finally got the page to load without errors but I don't see anything. When filling in DataTable, should I do it twice to take into account I used parameter twice? `dt = GetData(q, params)  dt = GetData(q, params2)`

Comment: I recommend to declare another `DataTable` instance and fill it with second query results if you don't want to overwrite `dt`. Using same instance twice will overwrite previous stored data.

Comment: This is actually a single query only. I think we got confused in the middle. Let me clarify further in another edit... Sorry if this is getting convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Join);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to *patch* together all the Rows values of a specific Column using as separator:  `", "` (comma + white space).

With the [DataTable.Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable.Rows);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) ([DataRowCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2)) as source, using the LINQ [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Select%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, you can transform the `Rows[Column]` content in the string format that you require.

A possible result:

```
Dim separator As String = ", "
Dim ColumnIndex as Integer = 0

Dim AllColumnValues As String = String.Join(separator, 
    dt1.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow).Select(Function(r) "'" + r(ColumnIndex).ToString() + "'"))
```

If you are referencing the `System.Data.DataSetExtension` assembly, you can use the [DataTable.AsEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.enumerablerowcollectionextensions.select?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Select%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) extension. The code could change like this:

```
Dim AllColumnValues As String = String.Join(separator,
    dt1.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) "'" + r(ColumnIndex).ToString() + "'"))
```

If some of the values can be null/empty, you might want to add a [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.enumerablerowcollectionextensions.where?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Where);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) clause, filtering the null values:

```
Dim AllColumnValues As String = String.Join(separator, 
    dt1.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(r) Not r.IsNull(ColumnIndex)).
        Select(Function(r) "'" + r(ColumnIndex).ToString() + "'"))
```